# Javascript promise execution timing issue

Tags: javascript, promise

I am just starting using JS promise concept and I have a problem understanding why two separate promises are actually 'dependent' in this example (that is, why if there is only "var promise" declared, execution time is 2.5 sec but when both "var promise" and "var promise2" are declared, execution delay for both is 10s).

If both declared, and only promise is executed, I would expect it to run in 2.5 sec. Yet once both are declared, console.log output appears with the same, longer delay. Why is that? Same if I add Promise.all, I would expect console.log output for promise to appear at 2.5 sec and Promise.all at 10 seconds but both appear at the same time.

```js
function runSlow(delay) {
  const start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < delay) { } // force a loop to wait 5 seconds is 5000
  return true;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // do a thing, possibly async, then…

        var it=runSlow(2500); 
        

      if (it) {
        resolve("Stuff worked!");
      }
      else {
        reject(Error("It broke"));
      }
    });


    var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // do a thing, possibly async, then…

        var it=runSlow(10000);
        
      if (it) {
        resolve("Stuff worked too!");
      }
      else {
        reject(Error("It broke too"));
      }
    });


    promise.then(function(result) {
      console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
    });



    /*
    Promise.all([promise, promise2]).then(values => { 
      console.log(values);   
    });
    */



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your `runSlow()` function is a terrible, terrible way to delay execution; it's a synchronous waste of CPU resources.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to play with some: https://jsfiddle.net/e35uv12o/

Comment: Promises are a tactic for dealing with asynchronous processes, not slow running processes.

Comment: Promises don't make tight synchronous loops (like your while loop) asynchronous ..

Comment: Yes, I get your points - terrible way of extending execution time to mimic complex asynchronous processing. And I see that jsfiddle example works by including another promise. BUT the question is: if I remove promise2 script runs in 2.5 sec. If I leave it uncommented, even if not executed, run time of promise is 10 sec...

Comment: @edaus also note that there is no need for Error() when you reject the promise. You can simply reject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to understand that the while loop in your `runSlow` function blocks the thread. This means that in your Promise, where you call `runSlow(2500)` the code is blocked (waits) for 2.5 seconds before it continues. Therefore, no matter how you write your code, it will always take as long as the longest `runSlow()` function you have specified. There is basically nothing asynchronous about the code. You can see this if you try the following in your code:

```js
// your code above

promise.then(val => console.log("I am done, 2.5 secs later", val))

console.log("I should show up immediately")
```

What you will notice is that the `console.log("I should show up immediately")` does not show up immediately, it is delayed by the 2.5 seconds.

The "correct" way to delay the function asynchronously is with this code:

```js
function runSlowAsync(delay) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay, true)
  })
}
```

Above the `runSlowAsync` function returns a Promise, that when resolved will have the value `true`. Here is the code with the asynchronous runSlow function:

```js
var promise = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  var it = await runSlowAsync(2500); 

  if (it) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke")) 
  }
});

var promise2 = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  var it = await runSlowAsync(10000);
        
  if (it) {
    resolve("Stuff worked too!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke too"));
  }
});
```

#### Now, how are the promises resolved?

If we continue with our code from above, when you use `promise.then(() => { //Do something })`, you are telling the runtime, ok, once this promise has resolved, `then` do something. Each promise will then be executed independently. If you use `Promise.all([promise, promise1]).then()`, you are telling the runtime to wait until all promises are resolved, before `then` doing something. Therefore in that case, your promises will be resolved only when the longest running one has been resolved. Here the code:

```js
promise.then(() => console.log("I am done 2.5 secs later"))
promise1.then(() => console.log("I am done 5 secs later"))

Promise.all([promise, promise1]).then(() => console.log("All promises resolved"))

// In your console you will see this.

// after 2.5 seconds
// "I am done 2.5 secs later"
// another 2.5 seconds later (after 5 seconds)
// "I am done 5 secs later"
// "All promises resolved"
```

Comment: I am getting error on this line: var it = async runSlowAsync(2500); Even if I have the function declared just above..

Comment: @edaus Yes, sorry. That should be await, not async. Please see amended answer.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Sebastian Ammon for taking time to provide extended explanation. Between your and Kaiido comments, I think I have a full picture of how this all works. Question if I may: whether it is better to write async functions as promises or just reference them from promises? Eg AJAX calls? How about synchronous processing of AJAX result?

Comment: async and await are just syntactic sugar for dealing with promises. Basically async and await "make" your code synchronous (within in the async function). It depends on what you're more comfortable with. A good resource is here: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 2):

#### Promise constructor runs synchronously.

So what you are doing is really

```
blockThreadFor5s();
scheduleMicroTask();

blockThreadFor5s();
scheduleMicroTask();
```

Promise reactions will get executed on the next microtask checkpoint, which will only happen when all the synchronous code has executed, i.e after both `blockThreadFor5s`.

Comment: Ah, MicroTasks... back to reading more then. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter at this point that these are microtasks. You can even simplify the concept with keeping setTimeout in mind instead if you are more familiar, the end result is the same here. The important point is that the function *fn* you pass in new Promise(fn)  is ran synchronously, while *callback* in .then(callback)  will get executed async.

Answer (score 1):

see comments, and run snippet

```js
function runSlow(delay) {
  // you were using while, that will block JS and lead to wrong result
  // this wont go wrong so no reject, but real world logic might
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("Stuff worked!"), delay))
}

// an async method that costs 2.5 sec
runSlow(2500).then(() => console.log(`2.5s later [2500]`))

// no doubt 10 sec
runSlow(10000).then(() => console.log(`10s later [10000]`))

// wait all things done
Promise.all([runSlow(2500), runSlow(10000)]).then(() => console.log(`10s later [all(2500,10000)]`))

// wait single done
Promise.race([runSlow(2500), runSlow(10000)]).then(() => console.log(`2.5s later [race(2500,10000)]`))
```